# Netty Add Channel to ServerBootstrap

Tags: java, tcp, client-server, netty

I have a ServerBootstrap accepting data from clients. Most of them are from any endpoint that connects to it, however I also want to handle data coming from a specific endpoint.

I'm reading and writing strings from n+1 connections basically. If the one specific connection ever closes, I would need to reopen it again.

Currently I'm trying to get a Bootstrap connected to the specific endpoint, and a ServerBootstrap handling all of the incoming connections, but the sync() that starts one of the Bootstraps blocks the rest of the application and I can't run the other one.

Or is it possible to just create a channel from scratch, connect to it, and add it to the EventLoopGroup?

Here's an example of what I have so far. Currently startServer() blocks at channelfuture.channel().closeFuture().sync()

```
private Channel mChannel;
private EventLoopGroup mListeningGroup;
private EventLoopGroup mSpeakingGroup;

public void startServer() {
    try {
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                .group(mListeningGroup, mSpeakingGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .childHandler(new ServerInitializer());
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(mListeningPort).sync();
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mListeningGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        mSpeakingGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

public void startClient() throws InterruptedException {
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
            .group(mSpeakingGroup)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .handler(new ClientInitializer());
    ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(mAddress,mPort).sync();
    mChannel = future.channel();
    mChannel.closeFuture().addListener((ChannelFutureListener) futureListener -> mChannel = null).sync();
}
```

Once data is read by any of the n+1 sockets it puts it's message into a PriorityQueue and a while loops continuously pops off the queue and writes the data to every Channel. Does anyone have any ideas in regards to the best way to approach this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to start the client and server in the same application, on the same thread?

Comment: Currently what I'm trying to do is open the client just far enough to create a channel and somehow add that channel to the same channel group as the server children.
This implementation creates the client and server sequentially.

Comment: Are you aware that `.sync()` means "wait till the operation is complete"? In your case you sync wait till the client channel is done